# i want the value of the input but it always alert 0

Tags: javascript

I want the value of the input but it always alert 0, how can I get the value of input

below, I cant get the value - the value of input is just numbers

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = Number($("#text").val())
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#p").text(text)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter a number" class="txt"><br>
<button id="btn">RUN</button>
<p id="p"></p>
```

Comment: You set the text on document ready and then never change it so it will never change from it's original value - move the setting of the text var inside your button click event

Comment: Your code is not reactive. It only runs once. You should add an event relating the function and the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you get the variable value when the page loads and you never get it later. You need to get it whenever you click the button. I have edited it for you and now it works.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn").click(function(){
          var text = Number($("#text").val())
          $("#p").text(text)
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you added a js library on your page?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

</head>
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter a number" class="txt"><br>
  <button id="btn">RUN</button>
 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn").click(function() {
        alert($("#text").val());
      })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```